# Diferença de tempo em Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou usando Entity Framework, e tenho uma condição que não tem funcionado muito bem:

```
.Where(x => ((DateTime.Now - (x.DataInicio.Value == null ? DateTime.Now : x.DataInicio.Value)).TotalMinutes) < x.Item.MinutosMaximo)
```

**Tipos**:

- `x.DataInicio.Value: DateTime?`
- `((...).TotalMinutes): Double`
- `x.Item.MinutosMaximo: int`

O erro retornado é:

> Os argumentos de DbArithmeticExpression devem ter um tipo numérico comum. Não é possível fazer casting e conversões em repositório.

Comment: acabei me esquecendo de colar aqui... Pergunta editada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você não pode fazer operações aritméticas com tipos `DateTime` quando está usando o EntityFramework.

**Se estiver usando o Entity Framework 5.0 ou posterior**

Você deve usar [`DbFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx).
Importe o namespace `System.Data.Entity` e sua query deverá ficar assim

```
.Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(DateTime.Now, 
                                    x.DataInicio.HasValue
                                      ? x.DataInicio.Value 
                                      : DateTime.Now) < x.Item.MinutosMaximo);
```

**Se estiver usando uma versão mais antiga**

Você deve usar a classe [`EntityFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx). Importe o namespace `System.Data.Objects` e sua query deverá ficar assim

```
.Where(x => EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(DateTime.Now, 
                                        x.DataInicio.HasValue
                                          ? x.DataInicio.Value 
                                          : DateTime.Now) < x.Item.MinutosMaximo);
```